# Mule ESB set payload from groovy

Tags: groovy, mule

I have manipulated data in Groovy script. I want to output of the variable of string type to be the payload. Directly from Groovy can I set the payload? If yes how. An example would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the payload from Groovy, we can just directly assign it, e.g.: `payload = theVariable`

For testing purpose we can try the following simple flow:

```
<flow name="simpleFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[int a = 1;
int b = a + 1;
String c = "Result: " + b;

payload = c;]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access global variable `payload` to access or to change payload. Also, you can return any groovy variable it will set to payload by the processor. 
like

```
<flow name="Flow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#[15]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[

             int b = payload + 1;
             String c = "Result: " + b;
             return c ;

]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
    <logger message="Final result :- #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Hope this helps.